# Create the same Form several times

Tags: c#, winforms

I need help I am currently programming notifications and I would like to create the same form several times, but always a bit lower this is my code.
I have everything I have ever learned already applied but it has not brought anything I hope that I find help here.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UniqueOS_
{
    public partial class alert : Form
    {

    public alert(string _message, AlertType type)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Nachricht.Text = _message;

        switch (type)
        {
            case AlertType.success:
                this.BackColor = Color.SeaGreen;
                this.pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.icons8_ok_70;
                break;
            case AlertType.info:
                this.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                this.pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.icons8_info_70;
                break;
            case AlertType.warning:
                this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 128, 0);
                this.pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.icons8_error_70__1_;
                break;
            case AlertType.error:
                this.BackColor = Color.Crimson;
                this.pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.icons8_error_70__1_;
                break;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    /// <param name="type"></param>
    public static void Show(string message, AlertType type)
    {
        new UniqueOS_.alert(message, type).Show();
    }


    private void alert_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
         this.TopMost = true;
         this.Top = -1 * (this.Height);
         this.Left = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - this.Width - 40;

         show.Start();
         button1.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = this.BackColor;                    
    }
    public enum AlertType
    {
        success, info, warning, error
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        close.Start();
    }
    int interval = 0;
    public void show_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Top < 60)
        {
            this.Top += interval;
            interval += 2;
        }
        else
        {
            show.Stop();
            interval += 4;
            Verschwindertimer.Start();
        }
    }
    private void close_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Opacity > 0)
        {
            this.Opacity -= 0.1;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Close();
        }

    }

    private void timeout_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Verschwindertimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        close.Start();
    }

    private void Nachricht_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Dear Roman a form is by default a classes that can be create serval time using the modifier new, so, all you must do is create it using this keyword. Change the classe construtur to change the position.

Comment: I dont know how can you explain me that ?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, create a new constructor to change the left and top properties. This will open a new instance of `form2` at the specified position.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public enum AlertType
    {
        success,
        info,
        warning,
        error
    }

    public partial class alert : Form
    {
        public alert()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public alert(string _message, AlertType type, int top, int left)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            this.Left = left;
            this.Top = top;

            this.Text = _message;

            switch (type)
            {
                case AlertType.success:
                    this.BackColor = Color.SeaGreen;
                    break;
                case AlertType.info:
                    this.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                    break;
                case AlertType.warning:
                    this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 128, 0);
                    break;
                case AlertType.error:
                    this.BackColor = Color.Crimson;
                    break;
            }

            this.Show();
        }

        private void alert_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should i add it into the Notification script (alert) or in my main Form where the notifications pop up?

Comment: You should call `InitializeComponent();` before changing those properties.  `InitializeComponent();` may change them back.

Comment: Add to notification, in main form call it

Comment: How do i call it?

Comment: Add to alert class construtor the two new parameters, like this `alert( string message, AlertType type, int top, int Left)`

Comment: Let me see if I can say this one more time: You should call InitializeComponent(); before changing those properties. InitializeComponent(); may change them back.

Comment: I want that if one notfication already exist the notfication form automaticly set the next notfication under the first notification

Comment: @RomanFuchs i have update my code to match with your. I can't do more.

Comment: Thank you @SérgioSereno for your help now is everything working